# Is it ok to exceed the number of columns of the parent column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following layout, using Twitter Bootstrap:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="span2"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="span2"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="span2"><img src="..."></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

When I need to display more than 4 `<img>`, I can just create another `row`.
But I've noticed that when I use more than 4 `span2` inside the `span8`, even without creating another `row`, it correctly splits them across several lines, rendering the same as if I had manually added the extra `row`s.

Is this a documented practice, or is it just working incidentally, and could have drawbacks in some situations / with some browsers?

Comment: I have problem with this, I wanted to do the same but in bootswatch slate theme there is different padding for first element and rest of them. So, I'll be watching your question to see if this is problem in bootswatch or I shoudln't be doing this :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK and it's documented. Take a look at [thumbnails section](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails) of the docs, you'll see an example of this practice.
By the way, if you are showing a collection of images you should be using `thumbnails`.

EDIT:
Despite of everything, there's a known issue when doing this inside a `row-fluid`. So there's only support for static content right now.